# phpunit mockery No matching handler found

Tags: phpunit, mockery

When I try to execute phpUnit with multiple test, someone fails with this output:

```
No matching handler found [...] Either the method was unexpected or its arguments matched no expected argument list for this method.
```

But if I execute the test alone, pass without errors. How I force to use different Mockery object in each test?

EDITED:

If I run phpunit separately, works fine and all test passed, but if I use the directory which contains the 2 classes... the 1st method passed but the second throw me this exception.

I have this method in the class AddCountryTest:

```
public function testAddCountry()
{

    $name      = 'test testAddCountryCommand';
    $iso     = 'derd';
    $telPrefix      = '+34 5';
    $languageId      = 1;

    /* @var WtsCqrsRequest $wtsCqrsRequest */
    $wtsCqrsRequest = \Mockery::mock('Wts\Country\App\Cqrs\Country\Request\AddCountryRequest')->makePartial();
    /** @noinspection PhpUndefinedMethodInspection */
    $wtsCqrsRequest
        ->shouldReceive('getIso')->andReturn($iso)
        ->shouldReceive('getTelPrefix')->andReturn($telPrefix)
        ->shouldReceive('getName')->andReturn($name)
        ->shouldReceive('getDefaultLanguageId')->andReturn($languageId)
    ;

    $commandHandler = $this->getCommandHandler($wtsCqrsRequest);
    /* @var Country $country */
    $country = $commandHandler->handle($wtsCqrsRequest);

    $this->assertEquals($country->getIso(), $iso);

}
```

and this one in  the class ReadCountryTest:

```
public function testReadCountry()
{


    $name      = 'test testAddCountryCommand';
    $iso     = 'zzz';
    $telPrefix      = '+34 5';
    $languageId      = 1;

    $this->createCountry($name,$iso,$telPrefix,$languageId);

    $iso     = 'aaa';
    $this->createCountry($name,$iso,$telPrefix,$languageId);

    $iso     = 'vvv';
    $this->createCountry($name,$iso,$telPrefix,$languageId);

    //Read
    /* @var WtsCqrsRequest $wtsCqrsRequest */
    $wtsCqrsRequest = \Mockery::mock('Wts\Country\App\Cqrs\Country\Request\ReadCountriesRequest')->makePartial();

    $commandHandler = $this->getCommandHandler($wtsCqrsRequest);

    /** @var WtsCqrsResponse $wtsCqrsResponse */
    $wtsCqrsResponse = $commandHandler->handle($wtsCqrsRequest);

    /* @var CountryDto[] countries */
    $countries = $wtsCqrsResponse->getData();

    /** @var CountryDto $countryRead */
    $this->assertEquals(count($countries), 3);

}
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you post some code to replicate the problem?

Comment: have you already see this https://github.com/padraic/mockery/issues/328?

Comment: @jack is not a comparasion problem i think

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I know this question is almost 7 years old but it's the first result that appeared on Google, so...

If the individual test works but if several of them run at the same time fails it is because you need to either manually reset Mockery or to implement the MockeryTestCase,

http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/reference/phpunit_integration.html

After that, all the tests would work as expected.